# Using g++ to compile, how do I point it to other .h files?

Tags: c++, include, g++

I'm trying to compile a .cpp + .h file that includes newmat.h and tinyxml.h - I have libnewmat.a and libtinyxml.a in the same directory as my .cpp and .h files and I'm running

```
g++ -lnewmat -ltinyxml test.cpp test.h
```

but still getting newmat.h and tinyxml.h not found at the beginning of compilation.  I'm obviously a total c++ newb because this seems like it should be trivial.

Comment: Why do you have test.h in your command line and not included in your cpp?

Comment: There's absolutely no point in specifying specify an .h file in the command line. It achieves absolutely nothing.

Comment: It can achieves something if his header contain some executable code (functions definitions [and not only declared] or variables initialisation), you never know ...

Comment: Little harsh there andrey?  It is in my cpp-  I don't normally compile command line so I wasn't sure what to include.  the -I. flag did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
g++ -lnewmat -ltinyxml -I. test.cpp
```

`-I.` to look the header files in the current folder and include your required .h in your .c files

Answer (score 5):

Use the `-I` flag to tell it what directory to look for include files.

Answer (score 2):

The `-I` switch is used for that, for example:

```
g++ -I/usr/include -lnewmat -ltinyxml test.cpp test.h
```

And if you want to add a path to the Library Search-Path you use `-L`, for example:

```
g++ -L/usr/lib -lnewmat -ltinyxml test.cpp test.h
```